# Identify if proc B's caller is proc A

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, session, stored-procedures

Is there any way I can know, each time procedure B runs, if it was called by procedure A?

I don't want to use context_info because it might be used by other procs in the call stack, and I want to avoid SESSION_CONTEXT (althought it seems the better solution) because many of my clients have versions <2016.

Comment: Sounds like you should be putting a logging process in Procedure A that denotes it reaches the line of code that calls Procedure B. Otherwise you could add an (optional) parameter to Procedure B that Procedure A uses to denote the call is from Procedure A and log that way within Procedure B.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? That is, once you've identified the call chain, what will you do with that information?

Comment: @Ben Thul Your comment is accurate, I realise I might have made a XY here. Adding things to question.

Answer (score 0):

It's ugly, but I guess you can use it:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.B
AS
BEGIN;

    SELECT IIF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#some_very_unique_name') IS NULL, 'A not called', 'A called');
    
END;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.A
AS
BEGIN;

    CREATE TABLE #some_very_unique_name
    (
        [does_not_maters] INT
    );

    EXEC dbo.B; 

END;

GO


EXEC dbo.B
EXEC dbo.A
```

Answer (score 0):

... ...

```
create or alter procedure procA
as
begin
    declare @hdoc int, @doc char(1);  
    --xml doc
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @doc;

    exec procB
    
    --remove xml doc
    exec sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc;   
end
go

create or alter procedure procB
as
begin
    declare @hdoc int, @doc char(1);  
    --xml doc
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hdoc OUTPUT, @doc;

    exec procC
    
    --remove xml doc
    exec sp_xml_removedocument @hdoc;   
end
go

create or alter procedure procC
as
begin
    select object_name(@@procid) as whoami, object_name(t.objectid) as whoiscalling, s.creation_time as at
    from sys.dm_exec_xml_handles(@@spid) as s
    cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s.sql_handle) as t;
end
go

exec procA
go

exec procB
go


drop procedure procA
go
drop procedure procB
go
drop procedure procC
go
```